# Using WHERE clause in SQL query causes error

Tags: php, sql

If I use the below code, it works

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ?';
```

But if I use WHERE clause to filter the exact user data, it shows error

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE member_name='.$userid.' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ?';
```

Here is the full error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/user/notifications/lib/DataSource.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/user/notifications/Model/Pagination.php(41): Phppot\DataSource->select('SELECT * FROM m...', 'ii', Array) #1 /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/user/notifications/index.php(7): Phppot\Pagination->getPage() #2 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/sitename.com/public_html/user/notifications/lib/DataSource.php on line 82
```

The funny thing is, I am using the same script with WHERE clause in another website.
but what could cause such an error ?
The `$userid` string has value, already checked and all included/connected php files are also working.

The code is from [this website](https://phppot.com/php/how-to-add-pagination-in-php-with-mysql/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I could not find the given code on that website. Neither does the code you've shared show anything else than a variable definition - is there more code you want to share? Nevertheless, be warned that your second query is open for SQL injection. It should **not** be used like that, never

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE member_name='$userid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ?";
```

Comment: That's still pretty vulnerable code. Is there any good reason to inject the `$userid` like that and not through a parameter?

Answer (score -1):

please change your field name (member_name) to another name.
I think member_name is an function like member() in mysql.
change your field name and try again.

Comment: Don't do this, unless you received an error message from MySQL that tells you so